# C# - Check if unix folder exists

Tags: c#, unix, sharpssh

I need to verify that a unix folder exists, from my C# application using SharpSsh.
I thought of trying this:

```
SshExec.RunCommand("-d " + folder)
```

But the result is always '2' regardless if the folder is there or not. I could implement  something using:

```
Sftp.GetFileList(folder)
```

But prefer not to because this folder may contain numerous files and It causes a delay while all of them are retrieved which is not elegant.
Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I tried this:

```
string folder = "/foldername";
string result = sshExec.RunCommand("[ -d " + folder + "] && echo 'true' || echo 'false'");

if (result == "false") 
throw new Exception("Directory " + foldername+ " + is not found.");
```

String 'result' is set as "false\n" even though the directory exists. If I skip the check I can  work with the directory without problems.

Comment: How about doing a bash script: `if [ -d {folder}]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi`?

Comment: Is this used like this: SshExec.RunCommand(if [ -d {folder}]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi?)

Comment: Yes, that's right, you should get back a yes or no.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> SshExec.RunCommand("ls -la  " + folder)

or

> SshExec.RunCommand("ls " + folder)

if your folder is not hidden and you dont need size information

Cheap command that will fill your output string with permissions and folder info if exists

Comment: OP says: "folder may contain numerous files". If you had hundreds of thousands of files in that folder... it's not very efficient.

Comment: You pass the folder name so it filters it

Comment: Try it "ls -la foldername" result should be one line or nothing if  it doesnt exist

Comment: The man says: "-a      Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.)." So, `ls -a` for 100k files with about 20 chars on average per file name will return about 2MB of data.

Comment: Its not ls -la. It is ls -la foldername.  If you dont put foldername you get all. With name you filter

Comment: It doesn't matter. `ls -la {folder}` means `ls -l -a {folder}`

Comment: -a its to include hidden folder with dot (.) Please just try to run the command giving the foldername at the end. If you look for folder "mypersonalfolder" put ls -l mypersonalfolder.

Comment: you dont even need the -a (if not hidden) and -s if you dont want size information, just "ls mypersonalfolder"

Comment: With ls you need the -d option, not -a

Comment: This command returns a list of files in the folder. If the folder is empty then it returns an empty string.